# How to avoid sorting when indexing Pandas MultiIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

When indexing a MultiIndexed pandas dataframe with two levels by the second level, the result is automatically sorted by index. Is there an elegant way to get the result without sorting?

Here is a toy example:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.ones((10, 3)), columns=list("ABC"))
>>> df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([range(5), list("AB")])
>>> df
       A    B    C
0 A  1.0  1.0  1.0
  B  1.0  1.0  1.0
1 A  1.0  1.0  1.0
  B  1.0  1.0  1.0
2 A  1.0  1.0  1.0
  B  1.0  1.0  1.0
3 A  1.0  1.0  1.0
  B  1.0  1.0  1.0
4 A  1.0  1.0  1.0
  B  1.0  1.0  1.0

>>> values = ["B", "A"]
>>> idx = pd.IndexSlice
>>> subset = df.loc[idx[:, values], values]
>>> subset
       B    A
0 A  1.0  1.0
  B  1.0  1.0
1 A  1.0  1.0
  B  1.0  1.0
2 A  1.0  1.0
  B  1.0  1.0
3 A  1.0  1.0
  B  1.0  1.0
4 A  1.0  1.0
  B  1.0  1.0
```

I would have expected the second level of the result's index to be in the order `["B", "A"]` -- similar to the selected columns -- but instead it is returned in sorted order.

So far aworkaround I've found is to reindex the result with `subset.reindex(index=values, level=1)`. Is there any way to do this in a more concise/elegant way, ideally that doesn't result in a copy of the dataframe? Why is the result sorted in the first place? It seems unintuitive in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably a decision made for performance. You can read about it in [Sorting a MultiIndex](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/advanced.html#sorting-a-multiindex), the takeaway being you want your index to be lexsorted, which is maintained by the current output of `.loc`. Had it given you your desired output, the index would not be lexsorted, which can lead to several issues. You should use `.reindex` as it will lead to a lexsorted `MultiIndex`.

---

Your original `DataFrame` is lexsorted:

```
df.index.is_lexsorted()
#True
```

The *unwanted* output you get maintains that sorting:

```
df.loc[idx[:, values], values].index.is_lexsorted()
#True
```

Had we modified the ordering with `.loc` we lose this sorting, and will now suffer performance issues according to the docs.

```
subset = df.loc[[(0, 'B'), (0, 'A')], ['B', 'A']]
#       B    A
#0 B  1.0  1.0
#  A  1.0  1.0

subset.index.is_lexsorted()
#False
```

Though reindexing does take longer, it would lead to a lexsorted index.

```
subset2 = df.reindex(index=values, level=1)
subset2.index.is_lexsorted()
#True
```

---

There are unintended consequenes when your `MultiIndex` is not lexsorted. So even though `subset` seems like it's sorted and that slicing the ranges should be possible, you can't. After `.reindex` the slicing is viable, because it's lexsorted:

```
subset.loc[(0,'B'): (0, 'A')]
#UnsortedIndexError: 'Key length (2) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (1)'

subset2.loc[(0,'B'): (0, 'A')]
#       A    B    C
#0 B  1.0  1.0  1.0
#  A  1.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense (although I still find the result un-intuitive). In my use case this is actually a dataframe of rolling covariance matrices, so maintaining the symmetric nature of each covariance matrix (where the rows and columns have the same order) is important. I guess I'll stick with reindexing for now.