# .loc into multindex pandas df on not-level zero with sorted order

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

say I have a multi index pandas data frame and I want to slice into the whole data frame on the not-zeroth level of the  data frame and get a dataframe back in the order of the sliced list.

this happens automatically using `.loc` on the zeroth level of the multi index, but apparently not-so for other levels.

here is what I mean:

```
# create a multiindex dataframe
index = [('a',1), ('b',2), ('c', 3)]
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index, names = ['letters', 'numbers'])
df = pd.DataFrame(index  = index, data = ['cat', 'dog', 'bird'],
                 columns = ['animal'])

# say I want to index on 'letters' level of df
lst_1 = ['c', 'a']
df2 = df.loc[lst_1 ] # this returns what I want in the order of lst

# now say I want to index on the 'numbers' level of df
lst_2 = [3, 2, 1]
df3 = df.loc(axis = 0)[:, lst_2] # PROBLEM: df3 is identical to df
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
                animal
letters numbers       
c       3         bird
b       2          dog
a       1          cat
```

but what df3 returns is

```
                animal
letters numbers       
a       1          cat
b       2          dog
c       3         bird
```

I want something where df3 is sorted as df2 is.

I can cheat and do `df.swaplevels()` but I'm querying my dataframe with multiple different sources that sometimes require subsetting on `"numbers"` and sometimes on `"letters"` and I hate, hate copying and recopying my dataframe while adding unnecessary lines of code.

thank you!

Comment: Could you add the expected output? When running your code I get df3 in reverse order of df

Comment: Hi @Chrysophylaxs, I edited the post to include my expected output.

Comment: df3 is the expected output for me. I'm using pandas 1.5.2

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54261500/how-to-avoid-sorting-when-indexing-pandas-multiindex